# TimeoutError: waiting for function failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Tags: puppeteer

I am using a puppeteer to grab some information based on a sheet. I use a FOR and, I need to jump into another link while running the FOR when I do that I get the error in the title and this line.

/Users/lucianohorta/Documents/Luciano/Projects/NodeJs-Projects/Admin-scrap/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:528
const timeoutError = new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`waiting for ${options.title} failed: timeout ${options.timeout}ms exceeded`);

I have tried the **page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0) and it didn’t work.**
Please can someone help me?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9 /**arrayStopPayment.length */; i++) {
    let ref = arrayStopPayment[i].PTX
    let trIds = ''
    let trxType = ''

    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="ppTransactionId"]')

    await page.type('input[name="ppTransactionId"]', ref)

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter', { delay: 100 })

    await page.waitForSelector('.merchant-reference', { delay: 100 })

    const referenceId = await page.$eval(
      '.merchant-reference',
      el => el.textContent
    )

    trxType = await page.$$eval('table tr td', anchors => {
      return anchors.map(links => links.textContent).slice(6, 7)
    })

    if (trxType[0] === 'External') {
      trIds = await page.$$eval('table tr td a', anchors => {
        return anchors.map(links => links.textContent).slice(7, 8)
      })
    } else {
      trIds = await page.$$eval('table tr td a', anchors => {
        return anchors.map(links => links.textContent).slice(0, 1)
      })
    }

    const amount = await page.$$eval('table tr td', anchors => {
      return anchors.map(links => links.textContent).slice(14, 15)
    })

    const amountUSD = 'USD ' + arrayStopPayment[i].AMOUNT

    await page.goto(`${pageDetails}${trIds}`, {
      waitUntil: 'load',
      timeout: 0
    })

    const signatureRef = await page.$$eval(
      '#fi-transaction .table-condensed tbody tr td',
      anchors => {
        return anchors.map(links => links.textContent).slice(5, 6)
      }
    )

    const objectRef = {
      CUSTOMER: arrayStopPayment[i].CUSTOMER,
      MERCHANT: arrayStopPayment[i].MERCHANT,
      AMOUNT: arrayStopPayment[i].AMOUNT,
      RET_REASON: arrayStopPayment[i].RET_REASON,
      PTX: arrayStopPayment[i].PTX,
      REF_ID: arrayStopPayment[i].REF_ID,
      MERCHANT_REF: referenceId,
      TRANSACTION_ID: trIds[0],
      AMOUNT_USD: amountUSD,
      SIGNATURE: signatureRef
    }

    dataArray.push(objectRef)

    await page.goBack()

    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="ppTransactionId"]')

    const ppTransactionId = await page.waitForSelector(
      'input[name="ppTransactionId"]'
    )

    await ppTransactionId.click({ clickCount: 3 })
    await ppTransactionId.press('Backspace')
  }
```

Comment: It's hard to help without a [mcve] including the site you're scraping and a step-by-step walkthrough of the code so far and what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything in **for** in `try...catch`

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the underlying problem, just suppresses the error.